# Where to configure MYSQL settings (such as sort_buffer_size) with Laravel's Homestead Vagrant Box?

Tags: mysql, laravel, vagrant, homestead

During the process of trying to install a package to my Laravel project with Composer, I have encountered the following error:

```
SQLSTATE[HY001]: Memory allocation error: 1038 Out of sort memory, consider increasing server sort buffer size
```

Searching this error tells me I need to increase the `sort_buffer_size` setting, something which is usually done in the /etc/mysql/my.cnf file. However, I don't understand how to tune settings like this using Vagrant- or in particular, the Homestead box. Is this something which can be set in the homestead.yaml file?

Comment: I think you could add those to the [yourappname]/config/database.php under mysql array. I would like to know if this is possible!

Answer (score 0):

As given in this [link](http://fideloper.com/laravel-pdo-connection-options), you can pass the MySQL options as an array with key 'options' in `[yourappname]/config/database.php` file.

Example:

```
<?php

return array(

    /* other settings removed for brevity */
    'connections' => array(


        'mysql' => array(
            'driver'    => 'mysql',
            'host'      => 'localhost',
            'database'  => 'database',
            'username'  => 'root',
            'password'  => '',
            'charset'   => 'utf8',
            'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
            'prefix'    => '',
            'options'   => array(
                'sort_buffer_size' => '100M', //set the value as desired
                //other options you want to set
            ),
        ),
        /* other connections removed for brevity */
    )
)
```

Comment: Thanks. However, this doesn't seem to make any difference in my case; I'm still hitting the same error...

Comment: Link to github issue: https://github.com/aimeos/aimeos-laravel/issues/99

Comment: what size you are using ?

Comment: Tried with various sizes, up to 100M as per your example. In the linked Github thread the developer states a value of 1M should be sufficient.

Comment: Also tried clearing cache and destroying/reloading the VM- to no avail.

Comment: can you try changing value in `/etc/mysql/my.cnf`

Comment: Changing that file requires SSH'ing into the Vagrant box and opening it somehow, which I can't seem to do on Windows 10. And can't find straightforward answers on it either. (I can SSH and navigate to the file but can't open it). This whole thing is beyond ridiculous at this stage.